# Maven: Add dependency to a project's module from another project

Tags: maven

I have parent maven project which contains modules A and B as follows:

```
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>root</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>A</module>
    <module>B</module>
</modules>
```

I want to add module A as a dependency to a new project without installing the whole parent project (only module A) due to dependency issues between the two projects. I got an error while trying to do so and I guess it is because module A's pom.xml file has the following parent tag. I wonder how I can resolve this. Thanks

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>root</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
```

Comment: You have to install the whole multi modules project afterwards you can use one of those modules as a dependency...

Comment: what is the error that you got ?

Comment: If you really want to avoid deploying th parent pom, you could use the flatten plugin to make A deployed with a reconstructed pom containing everything it needs, bypassing the need to deploy the parent pom.  But I would argue against it as flattening has caveats...
What is the problem with deploying the parent pom ? I think this is what you should solve...

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by deploying the parent pom ? copy parent's pom.xml it to the directory in .m2?